# Implementation of modulus function on sage-math

Tags: sage

I am implementing simple modulus function on sage jupitar notebook. The function is as follows:
Mod<sub>2</sub>(v,b)=(v+b*(q-1)/2) mod q mod 2

The function is wriiten in sage as :

```
def modulus(v,b):  
q=12289   
c=[]  
for i in range(len(v)):      
    c.append(mod(((v[i]+b[i]*(q-1)//2)%q),2))  
return c
```

The function is executed as :

```
dimension = 1024     # degree of polynomials
modulus = 12289 
R.<X> = PolynomialRing(GF(modulus),)      Gaussian field of integers  
Y.<x> = R.quotient(X^(dimension) + 1)   # Cyclotomic field   
pi=Y.random_element()
c=Y.random_element()
xi=Y.random_element()
sj=Y.random_element()
rj=Y.random_element()
gj=Y.random_element()
kj=((pi*c+xi)*(sj*d+rj)+(2*c*gj))

# Now, We are making another list named mon and calling the modulus function

mon=[1,2,6,5,8]      
modulus(kj.list(),mon)
```

I get following error while executing the above code.

TypeError: 'sage.rings.integer.Integer' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error nearly always happens when you try to do something that Sage translates as `1(3)`.  In this case, you have redefined something!

```
def modulus(v,b):
```

versus

```
modulus = 12289
```

You can't overload things this way in Python.  Sage will replace what `modulus` refers to by that number; your function is just gone now.  So when you do

```
modulus(kj.list(),mon)
```

you are trying to call 12289 as a function.

I suggest calling your other modulus `modulus1` or something like that.  Do it consistently, and this problem should disappear.  Good luck.